# Flutter: How to place the AlertDialog's actions at the top of its body?

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

Normally the `AlertDialog`'s actions are placed at the bottom of the dialog. I wonder if it would be possible to place them not at the bottom but at the top. I've read the documentation:

[image]and it seems this it not possible using `actions`. Maybe I'm wrong. I'd rather not have to place the actions in the `AlertDialog`'s title as a workaround. One could also place everything inside a `Container` and then just simply handle the widgets inside it, but I'm wondering if there's something that could be achieved less manually. I'd thank you any other approach you would like to share.

Here is an image to show what could be a desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve this is, as you said, using a `Container` and add whatever you need for the `AlertDialog` to look as you want.

Comment: I think it is in fact the only way. At least the resonance of this post shows that...